# How do I get data from another object which does not have a master-detail relationship?

Tags: trigger, related-list, master-detail, roll-up-summary, cross-object

I'm working for a nonprofit. We have a customized object called `Program Participation` which has a lookup to the `Contact` object and also is the parent of three other objects. We want to create a field on the `Account` page for each school to **count** the number of students they have brought into our programs with several filters related to `Program Participation` object. There is no master-detail relationship between `Account` and `Program Participation`. And since the `Program Participation` object is already the parent of other objects, I was not able to create a master-detail relationship with `Account` object.

I tried to create a roll-up field on `Account` level and the drop-down summarized object list does not contain `Program Participation` object due to the lack of master-detail relationship. However, on school page, we do have 'program participation (School Attending)' in the related list, which we believe there is a way to retrieve data from another object although there is no master-detail relationship between them.

Answer (score 2):

[@AndrewFawcett](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/286/andrew-fawcett) built a great tool to do just what you are trying to achieve:

> ## [Declarative Rollups for Lookups!](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)
>
> ### Features Summary
>
> - Rollup information between Lookup relationships not previously possible without writing Apex Triggers
> - Define rollups using standard UI declaratively, no coding required
> - Define filter criteria on rollups for example Rollup Amount on Opportunity onto Account for Closed Won
> - Supports Realtime, Scheduled and Developer API modes
> - Open source, available in code and managed package form.
> - Managed package has passed Salesforce Security Review and is Aloha enabled (does not consume app, tab limits)
> - NEW Supports Custom Metadata, rollups can be included in Change Sets and Packages for easier deployment

Answer (score 1):

As @Adrian mentioned already, Declarative Rollups above is an excellent tool.

There is also an app on the app exchange called Rollup Helper that also works well in this situations

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI